# Hangman picture is halfed

Tags: java, image, swing, layout-manager

```
public Hangman(){

    Container content =getContentPane();
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

   btnAddWord.addActionListener(this);
   btnRestart.addActionListener(this);
   btnHelp.addActionListener(this);
   btnExit.addActionListener(this);

   panel2.add(label);
   panel3.add(word);
   panel4.add(btnAddWord);
   panel4.add(btnRestart);
   panel4.add(btnHelp);
   panel4.add(btnExit);
```

---

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    Hangman frame = new Hangman();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 600);
    frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(panel4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

Okay so I figure out HOW TO CHANGE THE PICTURE when the wrong button is clicked but problem is the picture is halfed, so something is wrong with my layout...

[image]

Comment: Did you mean wrong == 6 in that last if-statement?

Comment: And what exactly is that label variable?

Comment: fixed it, I moved it to my buttons

Comment: @user1614977 You can't have two panels in the south position...

Comment: Even when I remove SOUTH from one panel nothing changes

Comment: When you apply the image to the label, you may need to call `invalidate()` on the frame

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so I wiped this up quickly.

```
public class HangPane extends JPanel {

    private JLabel lblImage;
    private JButton btnAction;
    private int guess = 0;

    public HangPane() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        lblImage = new JLabel();
        lblImage.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(46, 172));
        lblImage.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        lblImage.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        btnAction = new JButton("Guess");

        String imageName = "HG0.png";
        lblImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageName));


        btnAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String imageName = "HG0.png";

                guess++;
                switch (guess) {
                    case 1:
                        imageName = "HG1.png";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        imageName = "HG2.png";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        imageName = "HG3.png";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        imageName = "HG4.png";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        imageName = "HG5.png";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        imageName = "HG6.png";
                        break;
                    default:
                        guess = 0;
                        break;
                }

                lblImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageName));

            }
        });

        add(lblImage, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnAction, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }
}
```

[image: Guess00][image: Guess01][image: Guess02][image: Guess03][image: Guess04][image: Guess05][image: Guess06]

This just lets you click through and see each step individually.

Some ideas.

You may need to set the preferred size of the label (although to be honest, I would have thought having the label in `CENTER` position would have taken care of this).

The size I used is only suitable for my own image, you'll need figure out your own.

Also, try setting the border of the components using something like a `LineBorder`.  This will tell you if it's a layout issue or a image/read issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am gonna take a wild guess here as your question lacks the relevant code and images, but I would guess that not all your images are of the same size.
Ust replacing tthe image in the CENTER with a bigger image will not automagically adjust the size of the parent JFrame.

MadProgrammer has already chown a nice example for the case where your images are the same size. If you have images of different sizes, i would opt for a panel with a CardLayout  containing all images, and add that panel to the CENTER